# How to trigger an Angular controller method when the internal state changes?

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the best way to make my Angular component call the bound method (in this example `isItemExpended`) when the inner data model changes?

TypeScript

```js
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  private expandedItems: Item[] = [];

  public isItemExpanded(item: Item): boolean {
    return this.expandedItems.indexOf(item) > -1;
  }
 
  ...
}
```

HTML

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div *ngIf="isItemExpanded(item)">
    ...
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Note: In my solution, the implementation of `isItemExpanded` is a bit more complicated, which is the reason for not having the condition directly in the HTML.

Comment: Which data model is being changed here?

Comment: Just fire changedetection by calling changedetectorRef.markForCheck method

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef){}

  private expandedItems: Item[] = [];

  public isItemExpanded(item: Item): boolean {
    return this.expandedItems.indexOf(item) > -1;
  }
  private listenModel() {
     model.changed$.subscribe() {this.cd.markForCheck()}
  }
  ...
}
```